# Texto confuso no diálogo de "retirar voto para fechar"

Tags: debate, localização

Ao retirar um voto para fechar uma pergunta, surge um diálogo com o texto:

> Tem certeza? (Você não pode votar novamente depois de cancelar.)

E logo abaixo, os botões "OK" e... "Cancelar"!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu entendi que não poderei votar novamente depois de *retirar meu voto*, mas não fica estranho o texto tal como está? Que tal dizer explicitamente:

> Tem certeza? (Você não poderá votar novamente depois de retirar seu voto.)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56877/como-cancelar-um-cancelamento